# Caching scope queries in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching, memcached

I am trying to implement Cache into my Laravel 5.0 project

Many of the examples I see online for caching are not scope queries, so I am a little confused. Here is a query/method from my Model that returns all my classes' concatenations of `subject_code` and `course_no`

```
/**
 * Get all course codes and titles
 * Used in the autocomplete search
 * @param $query
 * @return mixed
 */
public function scopeAllCourseNo($query) {
    return $query
        ->orderBy('course_no')
        ->groupBy(
            DB::raw("subject_code || ' ' ||  course_no")
        )
        ->get()
        ;
}
```

As the first line of the method is simply a return, I am curious as to where I can put the `Cache::add('', $allClasses, 30);` query? And where do I put:

```
if (Cache::has('allClasses'))
{
  return Cache::get('allClasses');
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't cache in your model. You cache in your controller.

So in your controller:

You can use Cache add(), but I prefer Cache::remember(). https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.html#method_remember

```
$classes = Cache::remember('classes', 60, function() {
    return Class::allCourseNo()->get();
});
```

Comment: Oh you are totally right. That's makes total sense. Thank you!

Comment: Hey Chris. Judging by the docs `Get an item from the cache, or store the default value`, I'm guessing this saves the item to cache, and if exists, get from cache as well?